# Vuex with axios call, context is unknown when the promise resolves

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm calling a restful service inside of my actions object in my store (Vuex store).
The call works fine, and I have data returned to me in the promise, but the context that was passed into the function at the top is not valid inside of "then" function.  I can't commit the data because commit is not valid, state is not valid ... it seems axios is running in a completely different context.
Axios is imported at the top of the store.js file, and the program builds and runs with no other errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my function:  ( this function is in the actions object of my vuex store)

```
getUserDataList( {commit,state} ) {

  const url = "http://example.com/api/FetchSomeData";

  axios.get(url, {
      params: {
        id: state.userId,
        password: state.userPwd
      },
      headers: {
        myapikey: '12345'
        myappkey: '678910'
      }
    })
    .then( ( response ) => {
       console.log("Response:", response.data.data);
         (data is returned here, is working fine)

       // **** PROBLEM HERE! *****
       //   commit is undefined
       //   state is undefined
       // ************************    
       commit('myMutation', response.data.data)  
   })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   })

}
```

Comment: post more code. is this a module? is this `store.js` ?  show more things around the code you have posted. nothing seems wrong in what u posted.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure.

```
getUserDataList (context) {
  const url = "http://example.com/api/FetchSomeData"

  axios
  .get(url, {
    params: {
      id: context.state.userId,
      password: context.state.userPwd
    },
    headers: {
      myapikey: '12345'
      myappkey: '678910'
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) => {
    context.commit('myMutation', response.data.data)  
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

And maybe your solution with destructuring assignment will work too, but try change the arrow function in .then() to classic function. So this:

```
.then( (response) => {
  commit('myMutation', response.data.data)  
})
```

to this:

```
.then(function (response) => {
  commit('myMutation', response.data.data)  
})
```

Comment: there shouldn't be a problem with his syntax.

Comment: One problem is possible. Older browser with JS w/o destructuring feature.

Comment: that's possible. but i guess he tested it first on chrome and not on ie6 :)

Comment: You never know :)

Comment: @LiranC Today was also asked the question about the specific JS functionality in IE4 :D

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems to be right. Are you calling the action like this: store.dispatch('getUserDataList')?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answers and help, but I solved the problem.  It seems I had the import statements at the top of the store.js file in the wrong order.  I'm not even sure what I started with, but this is whats working now ...

import Vue from 'vue'

import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

import axios from 'axios';

Problem solved!
Thanks again.